# Avoiding spaces in Sql query within Vb.Net application

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a database table in which i have two these fields : **prix min** and **prix max**

When i try to update my table

```
 Public Shared Sub updatetraitementprix(ByVal min As Double, ByVal max As Double, ByVal ref As Integer)

        Dim MaConnexion As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Try
            MaConnexion = OuvrirConnection()
            Dim sql As String = "update traitementprix set prix min=@min , prix max=@max  where Ref=@refer"

            Dim Commande As New SqlCommand(sql, MaConnexion)

            Commande.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Commande.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@refer", ref))
            Commande.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@min", min))
            Commande.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@max", max))
            Commande.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch
        Finally
            If MaConnexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MaConnexion.Close()
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub
```

i have an error of Sql Syntax because of the space in the names of the fields.

1. So how can i avoid this problem ?
2. How can i make the Sql query ignore the space in the names of the fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use square brackets. Do this:

```
"update traitementprix set [prix min]=@min, [prix max]=@max where Ref=@refer"
```

From the documentation:

> The name of a result set column is an identifier. If the name is a
>   regular identifier that follows the rules for identifiers, it does not
>   have to be delimited. If the name does not follow the rules for
>   identifiers it must be delimited using either brackets ([]) or double
>   quotation marks (""). Double quotation marks can be used to delimit
>   result set column names, regardless of the setting of the
>   QUOTED_IDENTIFIER option.

And, the answer to the first part of the query is of course to only use [identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) without white spaces (or other characters that break the rules for regular identifiers).

See [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information of the various classes of identifiers.

Comment: ^ This. And to add to this answer (and to answer question 1: `So how can i avoid this problem ?`) >> Don't use spaces in your fieldnames in the first place. Or at least try to avoid them.

Comment: @RobIII Indeed. Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put square brackets around the field name containing the space.